# jsoup перестал работать

Tags: android, jsoup

Работало все прекрасно и  один момент не могу прочитать с сайта информацию по классам, как это делал раньше? Не понимаю в чем проблема? По tag вытаскиваю, титул читаю а вот конкретный класс не могу

```
try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://...").get();
        
        Elements table = doc.getElementsByClass("weight");
      
        Log.d("MyLog","Title : " + table.get(0).text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

и раньше все было отлично! А теперь null!

Comment: может покажете как читаете и вытаскиваете?

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том что сайт изменился и таких элементов больше нет в коде страницы.

Comment: Может быть и так, но когда открываю код страницы, все есть(((

Comment: Я уже даже все данные стер! Код открывается тот же

Comment: Для ПК и для мобильника, а также для разных браузеров и ОС могут выдаваться разные страницы - вам нужно смотреть именно тот код, который получает ваше приложение. Плюс не забываем про авторизацию, если она есть - тоже может выдаваться разный контент для авторизованных и нет. Плюс `Jsoup` не выполняет JS и, соответственно, динамически создаваемый/изменяемый контент не может получить. Вообще парсинг сайта дело неблагодарное - в любой момент может поломаться из-за изменений. Если вы его владелец - тогда можно что-то гарантировать, но лучше API написать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за комментарий. ))